# Is there a good way how to combine two contact forms in one?

Tags: forms

So insurance company customers have an access to their services through log in. One of the services is ability to ask questions to doctors/nurses and receive support from them.

Currently there are 2 forms actually: one is e-mail query, second is request a call back. Two types of how to get support from the service.

So the question is: what do you guys advise to do - to have 2 separate forms one after another or to combine it in one form? If you advise me to combine them, what is the smart way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I think this starts with: **what is your intended support path for customers?**

There are several different possible rationales that I can think of for having two contact methods:

- *Catering to customer preference* - the two are basically equivalent, and the customer can choose whichever they like (and once choosing one they are unlikely to switch to the other contact mode).
- *Different methods based on urgency* - phone calls are for more urgent query
- *Email as preferred mode, with phone calls as a fall-back.* - If the email is not able to answer a customer's question, speaking on the phone can solve the issue.

Another issue here is: **Do you need to capture the same information in each case?**

For an email enquiry, you need to get all of the information up front to answer the question, but a phone conversation allows more information to be obtained on the phone.  So it may imply different forms are needed.

I think if you clarify the support path and the information requirements, what to do about the forms should become clear.

**Ultimately, whether one form or two exists on the website is irrelevant to the user, but the user should be presented with a clear path and options to get needed support; there shouldn't be multiple paths that make it unclear which one should be selected.**

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a better experience to have one form but ask the customer to choose their preferred method of contact, like so:

[image]

Allow the customer to provide a description of their issue and below it, ask them to pick their preferred method of contact.